# Exporting jpegs from bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I record my bag file using this command:

```
rosbag record /camera/rgb/image_raw -O kinectrgb
```

And

```
rosbag info kinectrgb.bag
```

For its content I get this:

```
path:        kinectrgb.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    6.2s
start:       Jun 20 2016 16:19:52.89 (1466432392.89)
end:         Jun 20 2016 16:19:59.09 (1466432399.09)
size:        162.7 MB
messages:    185
compression: none [185/185 chunks]
types:       sensor_msgs/Image [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
topics:      /camera/rgb/image_raw   185 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
```

But when I try to extract the images I don't get anything..

```
roslaunch export.launch
```

It says process has finished cleanly but I don't get the images in `ROS_HOME` `~/.ros`

```
... logging to /home/jros/.ros/log/ff16c6e0-36f1-11e6-b3d4-5c260a35b6aa/roslaunch-jros-1932.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://jros:36064/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.19

NODES
  /
    extract (image_view/extract_images)
    rosbag (rosbag/play)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rosbag-1]: started with pid [1950]
process[extract-2]: started with pid [1951]
[ INFO] [1466432724.837729370]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.100000
[rosbag-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/jros/.ros/log/ff16c6e0-36f1-11e6-b3d4-5c260a35b6aa/rosbag-1*.log
```

My launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-d 2 $(find imagesequencekinect)/kinectrgb.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

What am I doing wrong?

What does -d 2 mean in the launch file arg?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237549/exporting-jpegs-from-bag-file/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you use the wrong topic name for extract_images in the launchfile

```
topics:      /camera/rgb/image_raw   185 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
```

vs

```
 <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
```

`-d` means "delay after advertising the topics before sending the first message" or as `rosbag play --help` puts it:

```
-d SEC, --delay=SEC   sleep SEC seconds after every advertise call (to allow subscribers to connect)
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1